# Compressing viewstate is adding another hidden field with same id as __VIEWSTATE

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to compress viewstate in ASP.Net 4.0, so the page loads more quickly for heavily bloated viewstate pages.

However, when I view source of page in browser, I am finding 2 hidden fields with same name and id of '__VIEWSTATE'.

My code is as below. **How can I compress the view state but let it be stored in its original hidden field without creating another duplicate hidden field?**

```
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
{
    byte[] viewStateArray;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _objectStateFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, viewState);
        viewStateArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__VIEWSTATE",
                 Convert.ToBase64String(GZip.Compress(viewStateArray)));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web.UI;
```

public class PageCompressed : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
private ObjectStateFormatter _formatter = new ObjectStateFormatter();
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    _formatter.Serialize(ms, viewState);
    byte[] viewStateArray = ms.ToArray();
    ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__CVIEWSTATE", Convert.ToBase64String(_Compress(viewStateArray)));
}
protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
{
    string vsString = Request.Form["__CVIEWSTATE"];
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(vsString);
    bytes = _DeCompress(bytes);
    return _formatter.Deserialize(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
}

private byte[] _Compress(byte[] inputBytes)
{
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(m, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
    zip.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
    zip.Close();
    return m.ToArray();
}
private byte[] _DeCompress(byte[] inputBytes)
{
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(inputBytes);
    MemoryStream mout = new MemoryStream();
    GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(m, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
    do
    {
        byte[] bBuffer = new byte[4097];
        int iRead = zip.Read(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.Length);
        if (iRead > 0)
        {
            mout.Write(bBuffer, 0, iRead);
        }
        else
        {
            break; 
        }
    } while (true);
    zip.Close();
    return mout.ToArray();
}
}
```

you can use this Interface Class to compress viewstate  by inheriting from it like this in code behind for every page

```
     public partial class Default : PageCompressed
```